# why is this question migrated here?

Tags: discussion

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21775/how-does-this-obfuscated-javascript-code-work

Is not a puzzle and it isn't related in any way to the site. So how come it is migrated from stackoverflow to here?

Comment: One more close vote, and it's back to Stack Overflow. Someone should talk to the mod that sent it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Stack Overflow moderators may be new or inexperienced. Newly-privileged users could have mistakenly migrated it here without knowing what the real purpose of this site is.

Perhaps it should be migrated to Code Review or back to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The mod who migrated it here was [Geore Stocker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker). Not exactly a newbie around SO. In any case - let's get this migration rejected. Also, migrating migrated questions is not possible. It's only possible to reject the bigration by closing the migrated question.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't see it in his activity... http://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker?tab=activity

Comment: most likely because it was already rejected (yay!). It was in the [revision history](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/21775/revisions) but it no longer is.

Comment: I don't get the answer deletions that happened during the rejection. The answers predated the migration.

Comment: Well I'm certainly glad it was rejected. I don't think it should have been migrated here in the first place.

Comment: Moderator talked to and apologised. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/pcg-migration-w-gs